# Using Laravel HTTP Client with concurrent request and Guzzle options

Tags: laravel, httpclient, guzzle, response-headers

Using Laravel 9, I'm running a pool of async http queries. However before fetching the body, I need to perform some verifications on the headers (*e.g. Content-type and Content-Length*)

Here is what I tried:

```
use GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

$responses = Http::pool(fn(Pool $pool) => [
    $pool->withOptions([
        RequestOptions::ON_HEADERS => function (ResponseInterface $response) {
            if (($length = $response->getHeaderLine('Content-Length')) > 1048576) {
                dump('Content-Length: ' . $length);
                throw new \Exception('The file is too big');
            }
        },
    ])->get('<15MB_FILE_URL>'),
]);

$response = $responses[0];
if ($response instanceof Response) {
    dump([
        'ok' => $response->ok(),
        'successful' => $response->successful(),
        'failed' => $response->failed(),
        'serverError' => $response->serverError(),
        'clientError' => $response->clientError(),
        'status' => $response->status(),
        'reason' => $response->reason(),
        'size' => strlen($response->body()),
    ]);
}

if ($response instanceof \Throwable) {
    $this->warn('error: ' . $response->getMessage());
}
```

And it produces the following output

```
"Content-Length: 15882755"

array:8 [
  "ok" => true
  "successful" => true
  "failed" => false
  "serverError" => false
  "clientError" => false
  "status" => 200
  "reason" => "OK"
  "size" => 0
]
```

According to the [Guzzle documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#on-headers):

> If an exception is thrown by the callable, then the promise associated with the response will be rejected with a GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException that wraps the exception that was thrown.

I was expecting the response to be an Exception, the same way I end up with a `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException` when the server is not reachable, though the response seems to be errorless, event if the content is not downloaded.

Is there a better way to check the Content-Length and Content-Type (*eventually after a redirection if needed*) of a given url to avoid downloading the content whenever the type is not supported or the length is higher than expected in a request concurrency context.

Thanks for helping

Comment: You spelled it incorrectly, Exeption != Exception - though, generally speaking, outright ignoring Exception\ConnectException are a bad idea. It should be logged, trigger some message or do some action.

Comment: Sorry, I can't find where you spotted 'Exeption' misspelled. I don't understand what makes you think I would ignore the ConnectException. That's the opposite, I need the Exception I'm throwing. Using only Guzzle, it works pretty well when I throw an exception in a callable, I endup with a failed promise and a RequestException, but not with the Http client of laravel.